# Windows Command line: Unset hidden and system attributes for all hidden files

Tags: command-line

If you want to make in command line in windows all files and directories non-hidden `attrib -s -h *` will not work.

Comment: Before you do this, are you just trying to view the hidden files in Explorer? If yes, you only need to edit a setting in Windows Explorer... not permanently discard the hidden setting of files! (Folder options > View > Show hidden files, folder and drives / Hide protected operating system files)

Comment: @ADTC Notice the self-answer.

Comment: Yes, just want to warn the asker that his command line script will permanently discard the hidden and system attribute for all files on his disk, whereas the options I mention will simply show these files in Explorer. It really looks like he just wants to see the files, not actually change their attributes to visible/non-system (I would consider changing them system-wide a very bad thing to do).

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I recursively clear the "Hidden" file flag on Windows Vista?](http://superuser.com/questions/295231/how-can-i-recursively-clear-the-hidden-file-flag-on-windows-vista), [Windows: How turn off hidden attribute for all files and directories on a drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/366561/windows-how-turn-off-hidden-attribute-for-all-files-and-directories-on-a-drive)

Comment: @techie007 Possibly. We still don't know whether he just wants to see them, or if he actually wants them unset as hidden and system.

Comment: @BlacklightShining He specified trying to use "Attrib", which removes the actual hidden attribute. Which is also what his title specifically refers to.  The solution he himself posted specifically removes the attribute, so I'm going to say that there's no reason to assume that's not what he wants to do. ;)

Comment: Related: [Quickest way to see hidden files on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/185122/quickest-way-to-see-hidden-files-on-windows?rq=1)

Answer (score 11):

You didn't mention which OS are you using, but since the command that you used

```
attrib -s -h *
```

didn't work, I'm guessing you used it without administrator priviliges.

The method I use is:

Run command prompt (Start -> Run -> CMD for XP, or for Vista and 7 Start -> type CMD in search box, right click and run as Administrator), type the following command:

```
attrib -H -S D:\yourfolder\*.* /S /D
```

This will remove the Hidden and System attribute of all files in the yourfolder folder on the D: drive.

The /S and /D arguments are optional.

/S will recurse ***down into all sub folders*** and

/D will **unhide the folders themselves** if they have the System or Hidden attribute set.

I regularly use this to clean customer virus infected flashdrives, as some viruses
tend to hide your files and replace them with infected copies of the virus itself.

Answer (score 0):

For hidden files:

```
for /f "delims=|" %x in ('dir /a:h /b') do @attrib -h "%x"
```

For system hidden files:

```
for /f "delims=|" %x in ('dir /a:sh /b') do @attrib -s -h "%x"
```

These will affect all hidden (and system) files and directories in the current directory

Comment: please take note of the comments